# For Next or a different loop for URL Icon Load

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I have an app that basically is a launcher for various web pages. I am trying to, OnLoad, to populate all the pictureBoxes in my form with the FavICON for each URL. 25 to be exact. Should I use a For and Next or some other kind of looping method? New to the looping part so all and any help is appreciated.

My code to load just one single PictureBox is the following:

```vb
Private Sub MainFormWPL_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Dim WebICON As New WebBrowser

    MainURLLoader.Navigate(Label1.Text)
    'URLText.Text = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
    Try
        Dim url As Uri = New Uri(Label1.Text)
        If url.HostNameType = UriHostNameType.Dns Then
            Dim icon = "http://" & url.Host & "/favicon.ico"
            Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(icon)
            Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Dim favicon = Image.FromStream(stream)
            PictureBox1.Image = favicon
        Else
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you have to use a loop if you want to load 25 images to 25 different controls, no?

Comment: I would think so. Since I need to go to each URL Favicon location to get and load each pciture box.

Comment: What's the difference, in your mind, between `FOR`, `WHILE` and `UNTIL`? Anything is fine.

Comment: How do you order the PictureBoxes? Here you have PictureBox1 but I assume you have 1 through 25, then how does each one correspond to a URL?

Comment: That is where I am stuck. I need to run the loop on load to check each URL I have saved (I am using a text file to load text boxes. Then, after that is where I want to go through them all and load the 25 picture boxes with the fav icons.

Comment: Loading 25 images from the web might slow down your application more than you hope. I would suggest you save them in a folder. Any loop will work, but I would suggest you don't use a label as the source of the url for instead use an internal list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Label1 --> PictureBox1, all the way to Label25 --> PictureBox25:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim matches() As Control
        For i As Integer = 1 To 25
            matches = Me.Controls.Find("Label" & i, True)
            If matches.Length > 0 Then
                Dim website As String = matches(0).Text
                matches = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i, True)
                If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then
                    Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
                    Task.Run(New Action(Sub() GetFavIcon(website, PB)))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetFavIcon(ByVal website As String, ByVal PB As PictureBox)
        Dim url As Uri = New Uri(website)
        If url.HostNameType = UriHostNameType.Dns Then
            Dim icon = "http://" & url.Host & "/favicon.ico"
            Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(icon)
            Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Dim favicon = Image.FromStream(stream)
            PB.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() PB.Image = favicon))
            response.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind... It somewhat runs. I get this error when I put it in a Try.  "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." For the test, I put them all as Youtube com as the label text.

Comment: That is what I had. Is there a way to slow it down to process each or is it something with my Internet connection possibly?

Comment: I loaded up my form with 25 different sets and it ran fine.  I would try it with just **one** though, change the loop, to figure it out.  Are all the controls named LabelXX and PictureBoxYY?

Comment: Yep. Each one PictureBox1 and so on. Label1 and so on. Here is the strange thing. I changed ALL the labels to be different URL and every time I run it, I get the error on the same links, every time. No matter what URL I put on them.

Comment: Sounds more like your form is "corrupt" somehow.  You could try deleting those labels and adding them back in.  Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: Ok, I removed all labels, added back new ones. Set the parameters and all works fine now. Thanks!